# How do I stop blazor @onclick re-rendering page

Tags: .net-core, onclick, blazor

I am using a blazor sever app

I have a control that when clicked using the @onclick event handler I want to navigate to a new page using the NavigationManager in the click event method.
it doesn't really matter what the control is (button, a, tr, etc) they all have the same behavior

if I put a break point in the HTML I can see the current page is re-rendering before it goes to the new page.

a simple way to reproduce this behavior is to make a new blazor project and in the counter.razor page
change the code to this

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

@if (1 == 1)
{
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
private void IncrementCount()
    {
        //currentCount++;
    }
}
```

put a break point on the HTML line "@if (1 == 1)"
when the button is clicked it calls the click event which does nothing (code commented out), it then re-renders the page and the break point is hit.
The same happens if I add code in the click event calling navigationManager to navigate away from the page, it re-renders before it leaves the page when nothing has changed on the page.

adding onclick:preventDefault and/or @onclick:stopPropagation does not change this

the only thing I have found that does work is adding

```
    private bool c_blnStopRendering = false;

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        if (c_blnStopRendering == true) { return false; }
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }
```

and setting the c_blnStopRendering = true; in the click event
but this seems like over kill and very manual to add it everywhere it is needed

Comment: Rendering should be a very inexpensive operation. Why do you want to stop it, what problem is it causing you?

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the reply. the main reason I want to stop this behavior is because I have a custom made grid component, it has a vertical scroll bar, and if I scroll down and click an item near the bottom, just before the page is left it re-renders and for a split second you see the grid redraw back to the top item (not where I was scrolled down too). And I guess the other reason is in all I have read it, I was under the impression Blazor would scan the DOM and only re-render if there was a change from the last render, in my example there is clearly no change to the HTML.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Blazor builds a render tree, compares it to the previous render tree, and only updates the differences. Can you make a repro? This is your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Peter. The code is out of a much larger project and I don't have time to make a smaller sample that reproduces the issue at the moment. the re-render with the scroll change is quite quick before leaving the page and I can work around it if needed with the ShouldRender method. thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

That's the only way to do it at the moment. There is a request in the backlog https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18919

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering how you got on with this. I had exactly the same problem (I just wanted to NavigateTo without any re-rendering). Overriding ShouldRender to return false, stopped everything - i.e. it didn't NavigateTo the URL. I was however, Navigating to the same page, but with different parameters in the QS. I seem to have solved the problem, (I think !) when I discovered an optional parameter in the NavigateTo method (`public void NavigateTo(string uri, bool forceLoad = false);`). I set that to true and it seems to be OK now. Was just interested in your experience

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30350622)